# ayuda al añadir informacion a una tabla dinamica

Tags: php, html, mysql, tablas

Tengo un intento de tabla dinámina. me conecto a la bd, pido los datos del comprador (customer): `id`, `nombre`, `address`. y quiero pegarlo en una tabla al cual se debería poner todos los customers pero sólo aparece 1, aquí les dejo el código.

```html
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","id11988295_admin","admin","id11988295_admin");
//consulta para traer el producto
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id ASC";

//ejecutar la consulta
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);

//guardamos en un array asociativo la información del producto.
$fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                               <th>Nombre</th>
                              <th>Direccion</th>
                              <th> </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $fila["id"];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $fila["flname"];?></td>
                         <td><?php echo $fila["address"];?></td>
                         <td><a href="checkorder.php?order&id=<?php echo $fila["id"];?>">Ver Mas</a></td>
                            </tr>
                   </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que se genere automáticamente otro "tr" con los "td" pero esta vez de otro customer (comprador), intente varias veces pero sólo logré que me saliera una sola tabla y 1 solo customer, espero su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Para ser más claro con lo que necesitas, ¿la línea de código `$fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` sabes si ya es correcta y con ésta ya has intentado extraer los valores recuperados de tu bd o ni eso está funcionando? Te lo comento porque es lo que necesitas iterar en orden de extraer los datos de cada registro devuelto de tu consulta principal.

Comment: la linea esta correcta, solamente que no se genera otra tabla para guardar el otro valor

Comment: ¿Cuántos registros totales te retorna tu consulta `SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id ASC` cuando ésta la copias y la ejecutas dentro de tu `phpmyadmin`, por poner un ejemplo?

Comment: en la tabla "customers" hay guardados 2 datos (2 compradores), ahora al momento de tratar de llamar a los compradores solo se inserta 1, especificamente no se genera otra tabla para insertar el comprador restante

Comment: Sabes, creo que no nos estamos entendiendo bien, ¿por qué no mejor nos realizas un boceto con lo que actualmente tienes y a dónde te gustaría llegar? Algo así como "esto es lo que tengo ahora" y "esto es lo que necesito obtener". Así das una idea más clara de lo que necesitas ya que creo que se están juntando muchas dudas que ni siquiera, creo, tienen que ver con tu problema principal.

Comment: esto es lo que tengo "https://bca-technology.000webhostapp.com/images/Screenshot_2020-01-26 Panel de control BCA Technology.png" y esto es como quiero que quede "https://bca-technology.000webhostapp.com/images/Screenshot_2020-01-26 Panel de control BCA Technology(1).png"

Comment: solo quiero que se genere otra trabla con los valores de otro comprador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de plantear la pregunta es confusa, porque hablas de *dos tablas*. Realmente lo que parece que quieres es que en una tabla te muestre en cada fila los registros que trae la consulta.

¿Por qué te muestra un registro? Por un motivo muy simple que conviene entender cuando trabajas con `mysqli` u otra API que conecta con la base de datos: los resultados de una consulta vienen en forma de recurso, una especie de puntero que luego tienes que recorrer para ir sacando los datos. Para hacer esto tienes que abrir un bucle (generalmente `while`) para ir sacando los datos fila por fila.

La clave, para entender, está en esta línea de tu código:

```
$fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Al aplicar `fetch_array` (o cualquier otro método `fetch` sobre `$resultado`, el puntero se mueve una vez solamente, y guarda en `$fila` el primer registro. Pero no hay más movimiento del puntero hacia las otras filas y por tanto no se leen más datos. Si por ejemplo hicieras esto:

```
$fila2 = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Tendrías en `$fila2` la segunda fila de resultados. Esto lo pongo sólo como ejemplo, no es que tengas que hacerlo así. Precisamente, para evitar ir sacando los datos a mano fila por fila, se abre un bucle y dentro de ese bucle se sacan los datos, algo así:

```
while ($fila =  $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //Aquí dentro se muestra o guarda cada columna de la fila
}
```

Explicado eso, vamos a aplicarlo en tu código, con algunas mejoras:

1. Evitaremos la mezcla de código PHP/HTML, para dar más claridad al código
2. Aplicaremos un método de lectura más específico que es [`fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). En el enlace podrás ver que el modo habitual de leer resultados es usando `while`

El código debería quedar así:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","id11988295_admin","admin","id11988295_admin");
    //consulta para traer el producto
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id ASC";

    //ejecutar la consulta
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

    #Las partes de la tabla que no se repiten deben quedar fuera del bucle
    $table="<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
    #Vamos a recorrer el puntero con los datos                    
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        #Empezamos a guardar las filas concatenando a $table
        #Aquí, dado que estamos en una concatenación, no ponemos " en las keys de $fila
        $table.="<tr>
                    <td>$fila[id]</td>
                    <td>$fila[flname]</td>
                    <td>$fila[address]</td>
                    <td><a href=\"checkorder.php?order&id=$fila[id]\">Ver Mas</a></td>
                </tr>";
    }
    #En la línea anterior cerramos el bucle
    #Aquí la parte restante de la tabla que no se repite
    $table.="</tbody>
            </table>";
    #Finalmente, imprimimos la tabla
    echo $table;
```

He tratado de explicarlo todo comentando el código entre líneas. Si todavía queda alguna duda lo puedes decir en comentarios.

Comment: y como quedaria si quiero conectarme a 2 tablas mas `orders` y `order_items`?. sabiendo que ya me conecte a `customers`

Comment: @AbrilLeguizamon tienes que unir las tablas mediante `JOIN`. Pero esa pregunta no tiene nada que ver con lo que expones aquí. ¿Esto resolvió el problema que exponías? Si es así, considera marcar la respuesta y si surgen más dudas plantéalas en una nueva pregunta.